# Checkmarx: Security vulnerability in uploading file (Cordova_File_Disclosure)

Tags: html, angular, checkmarx

I have the following code as input file dialog for user to upload a file:

```
<input #FileSelectInputDialog id="UserFile" type="file" style="display:none" (change)="onFileChange($event)"  [multiple]="false" [accept]="'application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'">
```

It's being flagged as having vulnerability by Checkmarx.

[image]

In my angular code, I read the file as follows:

```
reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
```

The thing is, user will need to upload the file from their local drive, and I cannot limit which folder in their laptop that they have to put the file. I'm not sure also on how to "sanitize" the input filename, as `target` itself is an object.

[image]

Any ideas?